# find filenames matching field values in msaccess

Tags: forms, vba, ms-access, match, filenames

I have a table with 2 fields 'name' and 'date'

I have a folder which contains some files which have name and date in their filename like so:
Andrew Dost_12Sep2013 04-59-58 PM_4.docx

My form should be able to loop through these files and fetch the files which match with name and date fields of form and attach them in email.

Can any guru help me ?

Thanks

Comment: Hey your code helped a lot. I changed it to make it work for me.
mypath = [Requester] & "_" & Format([Date], "ddMMMyyyy hh-nn AMPM") & "_" & "*.*"
  MyName = Dir("C:\Email Attachments\" & mypath)    ' Retrieve the first entry of matched files

  Do While MyName <> ""    ' Start the loop of matched files
      ' DO what you want with file named MyName
      .Attachments.Add MyName
       
      MyName = Dir ' next matched file
  Loop             ' next matched file

I am having problem in attaching MyName as variable. I don't want to enter full path filename, just the variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look "Dir Function Example"

---

```
set rst=openrecordset("TaleWith2fields")

while not rst.eof ' cycle through rows

  MyPath = rst![name] & "_" & rst![date] & "*.docx"
  MyName = Dir(MyPath)    ' Retrieve the first entry of matched files

  Do While MyName <> ""    ' Start the loop of matched files
      ' DO what you want with file named MyName
      '          

      MyName = Dir ' next matched file
  Loop             ' next matched file

  rst.movenext ' next row in table   
wend               ' next row in table
```

---